# Find the documents in mongoose whose array fields exactly match

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm using Mongoose and have a schema like this:

```
var chat = new mongoose.Schema({
    chatId : String,
    members : [{
        id : String,
        name : String
    }]
});
```

Suppose I have two chat document like this

```
{
    chatId : 'Edcjjb',
    members : [
        {
            id : 'a1',
            name : 'aaa'
        },
        {
            id : 'b1',
        name : 'bbb'
        }
    ]
}

{
    chatId : 'Fxcjjb',
    members : [
        {
            id : 'a1',
            name : 'aaa'
        },
        {
            id : 'b1',
            name : 'bbb'
        },      
        {
            id : 'c1',
            name : 'ccc'
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to find all those documents which have only specfied members Id.

For example, if I specify a1 and b1
then only the first document should be retrieved as the second document contains id c1 as well.

And if I specifiy a1,b1,c1 
then only second document should be specified.

Please tell me how to do this in mongoose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a clause on the array size, like

`{ members : { $size : 2 } }` in your first example and

`{ members : { $size : 3 } }` in the second one.

Can that work for you?

EDIT: I should also mention that the other part of the query should be

```
{ "members.id": { $all: [ "a1" , "b1" ] } }
```

and, for the second example,

```
{ "members.id": { $all: [ "a1" , "b1", "c1" ] } }
```